# SQL table constraint on column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two table Users and Appointements.
In the User table I got the following fields:
Id_user, email, lastName, FirstName, hash, salt.
I put a CONSTRAINT [UNQ_email] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([email] ASC).

In the Appointement I got the following fields:
Id_Appointement, doctorName, date_App, time_App, patientLstName, patientFirstName, patientFirstName, IsAvailable, email.
I put a CONSTRAINT [fk_emailPatient] FOREIGN KEY ([emailPatient]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([email])

I will like to do something similar to this but with the lastName and FirstName.

Any idea on how to do this since there are not a KEY.  Which constraint I can put in this case?

Here are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
   [Id_user]  INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [email] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [hash]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [salt]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [lastName]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
   [firstName]   NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id_user] ASC),
   CONSTRAINT [UNQ_email] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([email] ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Apointement] (
   [Id_Appointement]             INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [doctor]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [dateApp]         DATE          NOT NULL,
   [heureApp]        TIME (7)      NOT NULL,
   [patientLstName]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
   [patientFirstName] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
   [IsAvailable]       BIT           NULL,
   [email]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([rdvId] ASC),
   CONSTRAINT [fk_emailPatient] FOREIGN KEY ([emailPatient]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([email])
   );
```

I will like to add a constraint on lastName and firstName but these can be NOT unique since we can have to person with the same lastname and firstname but with a different email address.

Thanks

Comment: afaik it is not possible to create a foreign key on a non-unique field. You need to add a relation field user_id int

Comment: that seems awfully redundant, why don't you normalize it to have an `Appointment` reference a `User`

Comment: how it works normally, every person is unique ?  or is it the system that create a unique key for each person ?

Comment: you just need a foreign key `Patient` in `Appointment` that holds the integer key for a User

Comment: I can use the USER_ID key ?

Comment: Yeah, i think it'd help you out to read up on normalization

Comment: Delete the patientLstName and FirstName from Appointment.  Add a CONSTRAINT [fk_patient] FOREIGN KEY ([IdPatient]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([IdPatient]).   Also add the idPatient as a FK in USERS